# How can I find inflection points of a data set?

Tags: matlab, graph

My codes finds inflection points and locations of them, but some points are missing. Is there any way to find correct points on MATLAB?

My data set is at the link: https://ctrlv.it/id/17947/243681442

[image: 1]

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself._ Also, most of the red points on your plot are not inflexion points at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36504-find-inflection-points-in-a-data-array) :

**findinflections.m**

```
% function [datapeaks datavalleys] = findinflections(plotswitch,datain)
% This program finds peaks
% Arguments: 
%   ploswitch: 0 or 1 : disable or enable plots (for debugging)
%   datain: 1D variable
% Dependencies:
% 
% Copyright (c) 2011, Arun Ramakrishnan
% All rights reserved.
% 
% Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
% modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
%     * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
%       notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
%     * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
%       notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
%       documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
%     * Neither the name of the <organization> nor the
%       names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products
%       derived from this software without specific prior written permission.
% 
% THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND
% ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED
% WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
% DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL <COPYRIGHT HOLDER> BE LIABLE FOR ANY
% DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES
% (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES;
% LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND
% ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
% (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
% SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

function [datapeaks datavalleys] = findinflections(plotswitch,datain)
% datain = gconv;
datad1=[diff(datain)];
mp = find(datad1>0);
mn = find(datad1<=0);

datapeaks = [];
for pindex = 1:length(mp)
    [maxvalue, maxindex] = max(datain(mp(pindex):mn(min(find(mn>mp(pindex))))));
    if ~isempty(maxindex)
        datapeaks = cat(1,datapeaks, floor(mean(maxindex))+mp(pindex)-1);
    end
end
datapeaks= unique(datapeaks);

datavalleys = [];
for pindex = 1:length(mn)
    [minvalue, minindex] = min(datain(mn(pindex):mp(min(find(mp>mn(pindex))))));
    if ~isempty(minindex)
        datavalleys = cat(1,datavalleys, floor(mean(minindex))+mn(pindex)-1);
    end
end
datavalleys= unique(datavalleys);

if (plotswitch) 
    plot(1:length(datain),datain,'k-',mp,datain(mp),'b.',mn,datain(mn),'r.',datapeaks,datain(datapeaks),'g.',datavalleys,datain(datavalleys),'c.');
end
```

Call it (Array **A** is your points):

```
[datapeaks, datavalleys]=findinflections(1,A);
```

Output :

[image]